# Input/output error on mounted usb disk

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ext4

I have an external usb disk mounted to my machine, and everything works fine for hours or days, but eventually I cannot access the disk anymore. When I try to list the mounted directory, I get

```
ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
```

A dmesg reveals:

```
[156100.871322] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): __ext4_read_dirblock:908: error reading directory block (ino 2, block 0)
[156100.871465] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:3928: inode #2: block 1057: comm ls: unable to read itable block
[156100.887673] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4868: IO failure
[156106.537551] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[156106.537607] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 121667584
[156106.537622] lost page write due to I/O error on sda1
[156106.537638] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
```

It seems like there bad blocks on the disk, but I am too much a novice to correctly decipher these messages. If that is the case (or some relevant alternative), how to I best go about fixing them?